# How can I enable "acceleration using solid-state hybrid drive"

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-acceleration, intel-rst, acceleration

My Laptop is a Lenovo Y5070-B that has an SSHD hard drive. SATA Controller Mode was in AHCI mode and it doesn't have RAID mode. There are only two options: AHCI and Compatible.

When I set this option in AHCI Mode, Windows works, but when I set this option to Compatible Mode, Windows does not work and restarts automatically.

How can I enable "acceleration using solid-state hybrid drive" in Intel Rapid Storage?

For more information:

```
SATA Controller Mode: 1. AHCI (is Selected) & 2. Compatible
BIOS Back Flash: Disable
Boot Mode: Legacy Support (is Selected) & 2. UEFI
Boot Priority: 1. Legacy First (is Selected) & 2. UEFI First
```

Comment: ahci is the mode you want, what are your trying to achieve?

Comment: i wanst best (minimum) boot time and best Performance in work with my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a Lenovo U41-70 with a 1TB/8GB WD Black SSHD , and from what I have read you also should have the same or the 500GB version of it. Firstly , try resetting the BIOS completely and update the intel RST drivers , that should fix it up .